# Getting message content with Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I would like to have a command like `$status idle` and it would do the follow

```
variblething = 'I am idle'
activity = discord.Game(name=variblething)
await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=activity)
```

then they can do `$message write what you want the status to be`
then it would change what the activity message is. I hope this all makes sense. My current code is the following

```
import discord
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('$helloThere'):
        await message.channel.send('General Kenobi')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I would highly advise that you use prefixes and the command decorators/functions.

This means that your `on_message()` function won't be a mile long. To set your bot's command prefix, you can do:

```
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix ='$')
```

This will allow you to make commands like so:

```
@bot.command()
async def changeStatus(ctx, *, status):

    if status == 'online':
        new_status = discord.Status.online
    elif status == 'offline':
        new_status = discord.Status.offline
    elif status == 'idle':
        new_status = discord.Status.idle
    elif status == 'dnd':
        new_status = discord.Status.dnd
    else:
        return

    await bot.change_presence(status=new_status, activity=discord.Game(f'I am {status}'))
```

Comment: I have never used `@bot.command` so what would the command be? Would it be `$status online activity`? Sorry if this is a silly question.

Comment: The documentation for commands can be found here: [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html).
For the command I made, the command in discord would be `$changeStatus online`. If you want the activity you'd need to change the functions parameters.

Comment: When i do `$changeStatus idle` it didn't do anything, it didn't have any errors in the console, and it didn't change the status, maybe im doing something wrong? I'm not sure.

Comment: The code works for me. You need to make sure to include the prefix and edit any variables such as bot to whatever you have it as.

Comment: It seems to change the activity, but it doesn't change the status.